# Fastlane always returns 'string not matched'

Tags: ios, fastlane

Can anyone help?
When deploying IOS App to AppStore by Fastlane, "String Not Matched" is there all the time.

Here is the output:

```
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:17.54]: Making sure the latest version on iTunes Connect matches '1.0' from the ipa file...
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:20.00]: '1.0' is the latest version on iTunes Connect
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.36]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/description.txt'...
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.36]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/keywords.txt'...
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.36]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/release_notes.txt'...
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.36]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/support_url.txt'...
WARN [2017-09-21 17:03:22.97]: Lane Context:
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.97]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios release", :BUILD_NUMBER=>"7", :IPA_OUTPUT_PATH=>"/Users/me/Desktop/xxx/xxx.ipa", :DSYM_OUTPUT_PATH=>"/Users/me/Desktop/xxx/xxx.app.dSYM.zip", :XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE=>"/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-09-21/xxx 2017-09-21 17.02.40.xcarchive"}
**ERROR [2017-09-21 17:03:22.98]: string not matched**
INFO [2017-09-21 17:03:22.98]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/Users/me/Desktop/xxx/fastlane/README.md'
```

Comment: Did you solve this? Have the same issue.

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8482 , it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue in one of your own scripts, possibly in the Fastfile. This happens in Ruby when you think you have a Hash but you actually have a String:

```
s = "a string"
s["position"] = "an other string"

IndexError: string not matched
```